# Windows Clang: Command-line too long

Tags: windows, clang, llvm

MSVC has an option to pass a file which contains additional command-line options, I am looking for a similar option in Clang for Windows (NOT clang-cl). Is there such an option for `clang` or `clang++`? Currently I am facing a "command-line too long" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clang supports passing extra flags using so-called [response files](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#response-files) that you specify with the `@file` syntax. So e.g. `clang @args` reads arguments (whitespace separated) from a file called `args`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's the same syntax that MSVC uses, convenient.

Comment: I so much hate clang's lack of documentation.
It's not even mentioned in the page https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html
I guess as they started as a compatible replacement for GCC, they built this very extremely bad habit of relying entirely on GCC's excellent documentation to save more time for themselves.

Comment: Bad documentation is just the apple way of software development,